# Magento2 add custom datepicker with ui component at grid listing with inline editing

Tags: datepicker, magento2, inline, editing

How i add a custom jquery date picker in grid with inline editing. I have add in the form but in inline editing i am facing issues. data are not save for inline editing with datepicker and don't have any error in console

Comment: Please add to the question the source code

Comment: https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-add-a-new-editing-inline-element-for-admin-grid-in-magento-2/

Comment: I dont now what are the use of record.js

Comment: <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magestore_OrderSuccess/js/grid/columns/tag</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magestore_OrderSuccess/grid/cells/tag</item>

Comment: What are the use of this tags in app/code/Magestore/OrderSuccess/view/ui_component/os_needverify_listing.xml